# for attribute in label behave differently in ie

Tags: html, css

For attribute perform differently in IE9 and IE10. When I clicking on label it is also checked-in checkbox in IE but in other browser it wont. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsqpZ/)

**//JS**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function show(){
    alert(0);
    }
    </script>
```

**//HTML**

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="test" /></td>
    <td><label for="test"><a href="javascript:show()">click</a></label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the onfocus or onchange event on the associated input element?

Comment: I'd chalk this up to undefined behavior. You're assigning two different meanings for a click to the "click" text: a label which binds to the checkbox, and a link. Which one takes precedence is ill defined I'd say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/):

> The label element's exact default presentation and behavior, in
>   particular **what its activation behavior might be**, if anything, should
>   **match the platform's label behavior**. The activation behavior of a
>   label element for events targeted at interactive content descendants
>   of a label element, and any descendants of those interactive content
>   descendants, must be to do nothing.
>
> For example, on platforms where clicking a checkbox label checks the
>   checkbox, clicking the label in the following snippet could trigger
>   the user agent to run synthetic click activation steps on the input
>   element, as if the element itself had been triggered by the user:
>
> [... snipped code sample ...]
>
> On other platforms, the behavior might be just to focus the control, or do
>   nothing.

The specs seem to leave a lot of freedom even though, basically, they say that on clicking on a label, if a browser really **has** to do something, then it should do what normally happens on the current platform.

For example, if I recall correctly, in Windows when you click on a label (in a Wdinows form) the checkbox receives the click as well, so this is what should happen in a browser running in Windows.

Again, since there is a lot of freedom, pretty much every browser does what it likes.

If the question, which is not very clear, is how to avoid this behaviour, you may have to work around it some way using jquery or javascript. This seems to work, after a first quick test in IE10:

```
<label for="test">
    <a href="#" onclick="show(); return false;">jitender</a>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

made a few changes, heres the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsqpZ/1/)
removed the link from label though

```
<label for="test" onclick="javascript:show()"> jitender</label>
```